# Create list of dicts from two lists without losing sorted order of one of the lists

Tags: python-2.7

From the following two lists

```
wcD = ['countD', 'countD', 'countD', 'countD', 'countD']

D2 = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

I need to create a list of dicts without losing the order of list D2

The constraint is that I want to modify this for use with AWS Lambda without having to upload additional packages.

This is the code that I wrote:

```
count = 0
z8 = []

while (count < len(wcD)):
    x1 = []
    x2 = [] 
    x1.append(D2.pop(0))
    x2.append(wcD.pop(0))

    for x in x1:
        zipped = zip(x2,x1)
        dd = dict(zipped)
        z8.append(dd)

    count = count + 1
print z8
```

Here is the output from that code

```
[{'countD': 0}, {'countD': 2}, {'countD': 1}]
```

I am looking for a simpler way and also this does not produce 5 dicts, instead it only produces 3 dicts in the list.

The desired output is the following

```
[{'countD': 0}, {'countD': 2}, {'countD': 1}, {'countD': 0}, {'countD': 0}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of list and dictionary comprehensions

```
[{k: v} for k, v in zip(wcD, D2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map(lambda item: {item[0]: item[1]}, zip(wcD, D2))
```

produces:

```
[{'countD': 0}, {'countD': 2}, {'countD': 1}, {'countD': 0}, {'countD': 0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is `while (count < len(wcD)):` The lenght of wcD will decrease as you execute due to `wcD.pop()`.

Just append the lenght to a variable before

```
wcD = ['countD', 'countD', 'countD', 'countD', 'countD']
D2 = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0]

count = 0
wcDLen = len(wcD)
z8 = []

while (count < wcDLen):
    x1 = []
    x2 = [] 
    x1.append(D2.pop(0))
    x2.append(wcD.pop(0))

    for x in x1:
        zipped = zip(x2,x1)
        dd = dict(zipped)
        z8.append(dd)

    count = count + 1
print z8
```

Comment: Thanks for the help